# Override method which returns dereference to "this"

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a method in the `Base` class which returns dereference to `this`. I would like to use this method in the `Derived` class but also extend it a little bit. The example will speak for itself:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
   private:
    int value = 0;

   public:
    int getValue() { return value; }
    virtual Base& increase() {
        value++;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
   public:
    Derived& increase() {
        Base::increase();
        if (getValue() == 1) std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;

        return *this;
    }
};
```

As I understand it, in the above implementation `Base::increase();` will simply increase some `value` in a temporarily allocated `Base` object. How can I fix it?

Comment: No, there's no temporary objects here. `Base::increase()` means calling the `increase()` implementation from the `Base` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Base::increase();` calls the base method on `this` (no temporary object involved).

You may even write it like that if it is clearer for you

```
this->Base::increase();
```

Comment: His example will compile.  Even C++98 had support for contra-variant return types in overriden functions.  See http://cpp.sh/3l52n  (Comment was response to mistaken "that won't compile" comment - which has been deleted)